# PnP powershell provision Site with webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, site, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I am dynamically creating sites (Modern sites/pages) and I want to add `embed` webpart with embedded code each time a site gets created.

How can I do that with PnP Powershell script?

Answer (score 1):

you should create a test page with all your web parts

then with pnp get your page as file

```
$toSave = $file.ListItemAllFields["CanvasContent1"]
```

in `$toSave`  there is html for WebParts

put  `$toSave` html in an text file

then add a page with `Add-PnPClientSidePage`

then get your page with `Get-PnPClientSidePage`

set property with your previoulsy save html:

```
$file.ListItemAllFields["CanvasContent1"] = "your html";
```

Update and publish your page:

[http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com][1]